# Migration tables with different level

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

When I have tables with relationship (parent and child table) can I migrate them together at once or I need to migrate the child first?

Comment: migrate the parent first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't migrate two tables at once, the code won't run in parallel processing

And migrating the child first will cause an error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `database`.`child` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

So you have to migrate the parent first

For example, imagine a User has a Pet (domestic animal)

We would have `users` table and a `pets` table setup

```php
Schema::create('pets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

If the filename for the pets migration is

```
2013_11_06_151235_create_pets_table.php
```

And the filename for the `users` migration is

```
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
```

You would get the error above, so you have to rename the `pets` table migration file to a date later than the one of `users`

for example

```
2015_11_06_151235_create_pets_table.php
```

Because Laravel will try to create a database table with a column referencing a column in a table that doesn't exist yet

Hope this helps

Comment: The table will exist when the code reaches, Laravel will start migrating from oldest to newest

Comment: I have two migrations in 2019, then I did what you said, I renamed the child to 2020, then I migrate, the child migration migrated successfully. But then now I want to migrate the parent, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have foreign key constraints, then you can migrate in any order. If you do have a Foreign Key (FK) however, then it depends on your scheme, also then you could benefit from specifying `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` rules to your tables. See the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for that.